# How to change JTable header font when using JTattoo look and feel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I use JTattoo look and feel in my project. I try to change font of table heading using the following code:

```
tbExpense.getTableHeader().setFont(new java.awt.Font("Kerala", 1, 14));
```

But it is not working.

my code

following code for internal frame, i apply jtatto look and feel in Mainframe. this is the subframe. all other components in the frame changed to jtattoo look and feel but i cant change the jtable header font

```
public class T extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
public T() {
    initComponents();
    tb.getTableHeader().setFont(new java.awt.Font("Kerala", 1, 14));
    tb.getTableHeader().repaint();
}
private void initComponents() {
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tb = new javax.swing.JTable();
    setClosable(true);
    setTitle("Hai");
    setVisible(true);
    tb.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null}, 
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tb);
    setBounds(0, 0, 461, 372);
}                                         
  private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
  private javax.swing.JTable tb;                   }
```

Comment: Tried calling `repaint` on the header: `tbExpense.getTableHeader().repaint()`?

Comment: tried it but not working

Comment: Please edit your answer (using the `edit` link below your question) and provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/): a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example.

Answer (score 2):

try that

`UIManager.put("TableHeader.font",new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18) );`